# Get transaction EOSJS

Tags: transactions, eosjs

I used the following function to get transaction with eosjs, but it doesn't display all the content.

```
(async () => {
  await rpc.history_get_transaction('188d9cba22eb1acbeff074d9c092b202808c1510f37b02798c286d00c9cc7b5d', 46632826)
})();
```

How can we get the value of the attribute "actions : [Array]" with eosjs.

```
 {
 id: '188d9cba22eb1acbeff074d9c092b202808c1510f37b02798c286d00c9cc7b5d',
 trx: {
   receipt: {
     status: 'executed',
     cpu_usage_us: 344,
     net_usage_words: 19,
     trx: [Array]
   },
   trx: {
     expiration: '2020-02-27T03:36:29',
     ref_block_num: 1126,
     ref_block_prefix: 2779202260,
     max_net_usage_words: 0,
     max_cpu_usage_ms: 0,
     delay_sec: 0,
     context_free_actions: [],
     actions: [Array],
     transaction_extensions: [],
     signatures: [Array],
     context_free_data: []
   }
 },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the JSON Object like this:

```
(async () => {
    let transaction = await rpc.history_get_transaction('188d9cba22eb1acbeff074d9c092b202808c1510f37b02798c286d00c9cc7b5d', 46632826);
    let actions = transaction.trx.trx.actions; // <---- All actions
    console.log("actions", actions);
    if (actions.length >= 1) {
        console.log("first action", actions[0]); // <---- First action
        console.log("stringified first action", JSON.stringify(actions[0])); // <---- First action, but as a string and not json object
    }
})();
```

Here is some more information about JSON:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Comment: Thank you for your answer Frank.

Comment: I have a question, my smart contract has only one action, does that mean that the transaction contains only one action. The idea is that every time I call the action in my smart contract, the transaction ID back is stored in a database. Once I need this data, I receive a transaction with the ID, so how do I know the rank of my action in the list of actions.